# Calloc implementation

Tags: c, memory, calloc, memset

I made a `ft_calloc` and `ft_memset`, they both work but I don't understand why.

```
void *ft_memset(void *s, int c, size_t n)
{
        size_t i;
        unsigned char *p;

        i = 0;
        p = (unsigned char *)s;
        while (i < n)
        {
                p[i] = (unsigned char)c;
                i++;
        }
        return ((void*)p);
}

void *ft_calloc(size_t nmemb, size_t size)
{
        void *s;

        if (!(s = malloc(size * nmemb)))
                return (NULL);
        s = ft_memset(s, 0, nmemb * size);
        return (s);
}
```

I don't understand why multiply `nmemb` and `size` in `ft_calloc` function.

Example:

In `(ft_calloc) nmemb = 5` and `size = 4`, `(ft_memset) size_t n = (5 * 4)`,
the variable `i` will over increment in the `while` loop, while I need to stop at the 5th element (`nmemb`) of the array. Is this correct?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, you are callocing 5 elements of 4 bytes each for a total of 20 bytes. `i` in the loop goes from 0 to 19 which is 20 bytes and you assign each byte in the loop the value of `c`

Comment: Aside: Robust code would guard against overflow prior to `malloc()` with `if (size && SIZE_MAX/size > nmemb) return NULL;`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica that's already covered by `malloc`, isn't it?

Comment: @MarcoBonelli No.  It is not possible for `malloc(n)` to know if `nmemb*size` overflowed in forming `n`.  BTW: 2nd test should be `SIZE_MAX/size < nmemb`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica ah, you're right. I was thinking about `calloc()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't understand why multiply `nmemb` and `size` in `ft_calloc` function

Because `ft_memset` operates at the byte level, setting every single byte to the given value. If you have `nmemb` elements of `size` bytes each, the total number of bytes is `nmemb * size`.

> In `(ft_calloc)nmemb = 5` and `size = 4`, `(ft_memset) size_t n = (5 * 4)`,
> the variable `i` will over increment in the `while` loop

No it will not. You are iterating over an `unsigned char *`. That is, each element is one byte. Since in `ft_calloc` you have `5` members each of size `4` bytes, the total number of bytes is `5 * 4 == 20`, which means if you use a pointer of type `unsigned char *` to iterate you will need to do `20` iterations. The code is correct.

---

**NOTE**: as [@chux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2410359/chux-reinstate-monica) states in the comments, you should check for overflow in your `ft_calloc()` *before* calling `malloc()` and make the function fail in case `nmemb * size` is too large:

```
if (size && SIZE_MAX/size < nmemb)
    return NULL;
```